# Is there an option in Apache to check PHP files for malicious code before parsing them?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, regex

Basically, I would like Apache to check PHP files for certain patterns before parsing them. If these PHP files match the patterns, I would like to send something else in replacement back to the user.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If your php files are writable to the apache user **that** is the problem to fix.

Comment: Thank you, @AD7six, your answer is very interesting! Yes, this would help me. And yes, you are right. But I would also like to prevent PHP file from being uploaded. I'm not sure what would be the best solution.

Comment: Not allowing arbitrary files to be uploaded to a web accessible location and/or ensuring that location doesn't parse any php (or any server-side script language) logic would be a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

If your users are trying to deploy malicious code, you may consider getting new users.

What is your use case here? Code review should happen completely outside of this process.

---

A couple additional thoughts in regards to your below comment:

1. If you think there may be an automated "virus scanner" type way to do this, you're going to be disappointed.
2. If you think that matching a few simple regex will be sufficient, you'll also be disappointed, as the number of regex you'd need to match for is nearly infinite.
3. The best you can do is architect your shared hosting server as to be as secure as possible - isolating each customer in their own container, perhaps, such that any damage they do is limited to their own account and cannot spread beyond that.

Comment: Thank you for answering :) I would like to secure my webserver for cases where a user uploads a website, but the website is vulnerable for bots and hackers to upload malicious code to the server. For example, if a Wordpress plugin is out of date, my entire webserver is vulnerable, because one user did not update Wordpress plugins. I do not want to continually need to check the websites of all users for vulnerable code. What would be the best way to go?

Comment: @MichielPater See my addition.

Comment: How would I be able to isolate users in containers?

Comment: That is a very broad question. You'll need to read up on the topic, form some idea of what you might do, and then try and implement it. Come back here with any specific questions you may have.

Answer (score 1):

***Forewarning:*** I'm suspicious as to why you are having this problem to begin with. If you believe that potentially malicious code could be put in a directory that apache serves, you may want to re-think your current web server setup.

With that being said, you could use [PHP's `disable_functions` config](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions). Functions may want to disable:

- exec
- system
- shell_exec
- popen
- allow_url_fopen
- allow_url_include

A sloppier solution would be to delete PHP files that match a regex:

```
find /var/www -iname '*.php' | xargs egrep -l '(eval|system)\(' | xargs rm
```

Did not test it but, of course, you should come up with your own command and be confident you understand it before implementing it.

Comment: While that would work, you're just helping the OP to ignore the real problem/mistake.

Comment: Generally would agree but I do not presume to know their exact use case. Just giving him/her an idea on a possible solution. I'll append to make that clear. Thanks.

Comment: I also don't know - It's likely one of these though: 1) Uncontrolled access to the file system, "someone" is writing php files 2) Insecure CMS install, such as wordpress, and it keeps getting hacked. Either way though - it's the wrong solution to have the need to grep the source code for hacks. Note also [the OP's question history](http://serverfault.com/questions/677633/how-can-i-disable-specific-file-type-uploads-globally-in-apache).

Comment: I could think of many other possibilities (e.g., multi-tenant apache server, user home sites that serves php, etc.). But your point is still valid.

Answer (score -2):

I think for what are you trying to accomplish you should have a look at [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/about.html).